# How to combine ortho imagery and a DSM to make a pointcloud

Tags: qgis, gdal, point-cloud, pdal

I can create a VRT with four rasters and convert this to GTiff.  But I don't seem to be able to create the point cloud from the GTiff.  I have tried:

```
pdal translate input.tif output.las --reader gdal
```

With poor results. Poor results means that I cannot see any elevation in the output file. The output.las file shows as a flat sheet in CloudCompare.

Here is the gdalinfo for input.tif:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: planoProject0409.tif
       planoProject0409.tif.aux.xml
Size is 262, 261
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 14N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 14N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-99,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],
        AREA["Between 102°W and 96°W, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore and offshore. Canada - Manitoba; Nunavut; Saskatchewan. Mexico. United States (USA)."],
        BBOX[0,-102,84,-96]],
    ID["EPSG",32614]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (699313.539800000027753,3666532.084100000094622)
Pixel Size = (0.999044656488273,-0.999044827587003)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  699313.540, 3666532.084) ( 96d51'49.35"W, 33d 7' 9.11"N)
Lower Left  (  699313.540, 3666271.333) ( 96d51'49.55"W, 33d 7' 0.65"N)
Upper Right (  699575.289, 3666532.084) ( 96d51'39.25"W, 33d 7' 8.94"N)
Lower Right (  699575.289, 3666271.333) ( 96d51'39.46"W, 33d 7' 0.48"N)
Center      (  699444.415, 3666401.709) ( 96d51'44.40"W, 33d 7' 4.79"N)
Band 1 Block=262x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=103.545, StdDev=58.812
  NoData Value=-9999
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=103.54479248925
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=58.811625988053
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Band 2 Block=262x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=254.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=254.000, Mean=99.858, StdDev=57.084
  NoData Value=-9999
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=254
    STATISTICS_MEAN=99.858471527595
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=57.084459039457
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Band 3 Block=262x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=94.319, StdDev=55.017
  NoData Value=-9999
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=94.318841215526
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=55.016610489976
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Band 4 Block=262x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-9999
```

Comment: I think it has to do with filters.colorization and/or filters.range

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/457321/edit) to include the output of either `pdal info input.tif` or `gdalinfo input.tif` and also define what you mean by "poor results".